# Automating remote desktop connection

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, remote-desktop

We use many remote desktops in our development environment and there are many servers deployed in multiple environments. It is tedious to remember their IP addresses, usernames, and passwords. I want to write a small utility with buttons on it. When clicked, I want to start those remote desktops, automatically fetching usernames and passwords from some list.

I know there is a command line equivalent for MS Remote Desktop: `mstsc`. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296819/run-mstsc-exe-with-specified-username-and-password) question suggests to do this as follows:

```
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/"computername or IP address" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
mstsc /v:"computer name or IP"
```

I run the first line, and it says credential successfully added. Then when I run the second line it simply runs Remote Desktop Connection for the specified IP address and asks for username and password. I would like it to simply open the remotely connected desktop at specified IP address by automatically applying the credential specified in `cmdkey`.

- What's wrong here? Is it possible using such PowerShell script?
- Can I invoke this script through an HTML page (since there are many other resources that I will be laying onto the webpage which will serve as one spot links for we developers, so that we will not be wasting time and effort finding them each time we want them)? Is it possible by [registering the application to a URI scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85))?
- Is there another (standard) way?

Comment: You cannot create buttons with powershell. PowerShell is a commmand line based language. For buttons, take a look to C# and Visual Studio Express

Comment: @Solaflex yes I know that I have to call this PowerShell scritps from app built using say .NET. Just removed that questions since I just realized that its very well possible.

Comment: Is the computer in a domain ?

Comment: yes All remotes computers are in a domain, I am able to connect to them using Remote Desktop Connection but not through PowerShell

Comment: Instead of /generic:TERMSRV/"computername or IP" try this:
/generic:YourDomain/"computername or IP"

Comment: hey well sorry I meant they or on LAN. Even when connecting through Remote Desktop Connection we directly put IPs, And since when I run the second line it shows the dialog asking for username and password it does mean that it finds the remote desktop at the specified IP but need username and password. I think somehow it is not using the credentials I have added.

Comment: hey just realized that it is selecting the presaved username and showing blank password field for input instead of using the username I specified in credentials

Comment: well my office network blocks chat page :( let us continue here only

Comment: ok, try this please:
cmdkey /generic:"computername or IP" /user:"username" /pass:"password"

Comment: Heya it worked can u just put in answer and explain what that meant? Well am noob in PowerShell

Comment: of course ;)
Wait a few miinutes
It has notihng to do with powershell

Comment: I editet and hope, that I can also answer your other questions.
If you need a C# Class to call powershell scripts from your ASP.NET Page, call me ;)

Comment: why dont you just use a rdp manager like royal ts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem in your attempt is the parameter `/generic`.

According to the [official website for cmdkey](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754243%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), `/generic`

> identifies the computer or domain name that this entry will be associated with.

In my example, I will call the computer ***Computer01***.

Do you want the credentials associated with TERMSRV/Computer01 ? (Like your example `/generic:TERMSRV/"computername or IP address "` said)

No, you want it associated to the normal computername ***Computer01***.

Then you have to remove `TERMSRV/`.

The working result is:

```
cmdkey /generic:"computername or IP" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
```

To your other questions:

1. See the answer above
2. I don't know if it's possible with HTML only. I don't think so. But I also implement some PowerShell scripts into ASP.NET. This works.
3. See answer above.

Comment: I tried it and it partially work in Windows 10. It asks for the password every time I use the batch script. Do you have any idea how do I make it work without promptly being asked for the password.

Answer (score 2):

A lot has changed since 2013. Many system operators already suggested to use ready-made tools which does this. Back in year 2013, Windows store wasn't that great a place (*my opinion). But now it's OK.

There is [Microsoft's own Remote Desktop application](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps) in the store. The application is universal, that is, it runs on PCs, mobile phones, and holographic devices.

What's good? Microsoft has [made the same app available on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android). I have tried for PC and Android. Both work great.

So have a try. I am regular user of these applications now.

Comment: It would be good if you added the minimum requirements: **Minimum  
OS**: Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 Mobile, Windows Phone 8.1
**Architecture**: ARM, x86, x64

Answer (score 0):

This partially worked for me in Windows. After entering the below two commands in command prompt, it will open RDP for the specified IP address. But still it asked me to enter the password for a different username (already saved username in Remote Desktop Connection) other than the username I entered in my cmd command. Since the administrator does not allow the use of saved credentials to log on to the remote computer.

```
start cmdkey /generic:"enter your IP address" /user:"enter your username" /pass:"enter your password"
start mstsc /f /v:"enter your IP address"
```