# Run mstsc in PowerShell without a password prompt

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, mstsc

I have a simple .ps1 file:

```
$Server="remotepc.company.net"
$User=".\login"
$Password="password"

cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$Server /user:$User /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server /h:1080 /w:1920
```

And anyway it asks for a password.

Comment: If the remote system is set to force you to ask for a password, then you can't bypass that on the client side. (Setting that on the server is a serverfault question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating remote desktop connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479652/automating-remote-desktop-connection)

Comment: I have access to server. What should I check at server to unset this behaviour?

Comment: Jeroen Mostert >> I read that question and I tried withot TERMSRV/ - does not work anyway

Comment: Ask on serverfault. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

In RDP, go to the option checked to always ask for credentials:

Launch RDP → *Show options* → *un-check *Always ask for credentials*.

It seems, even though you gave credentials correctly, this was still making RDP ask.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in `$User=".\login"`.

`login` is a local user name (not domain).

So to force it to work:

```
$User="localhost\login"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$Server="remotepc.company.net"
$User="localhost\login"
$Password="password"
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

cmdkey /generic:$Server /user:$User /pass:$SecurePassword
mstsc /v:$Server /h:1080 /w:1920
```

Comment: with the removed TERMSERV?

Comment: with and without

Comment: @WillWebb: `cmdkey` expects an _unencrypted_ password with `/pass` (it does its own encryption before storing it), so this won't work.

Comment: @WillWebb: Can I suggest you either revise or delete your answer?

Comment: Answer updated, issue was within the ".\login" part of $User variable.