# RDP from Powershell command-line

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

I'm having trouble creating a Powershell script that will open an RDP session without a prompt asking for a password.

I've followed the instructions in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479652/automating-remote-desktop-connection), however the password prompt always pops up.

Here is the script:

```
cmdkey /generic:"server ip" /user:"username" /pass:"password"
mstsc /v:"server ip"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is it possible to execute within the realm of Powershell? Thanks!

Comment: are you using a domain user or local user to connect to the computer

Comment: Im using a local user

Comment: try using ".\username"  your script worked for me

Comment: Alright, Ill try it tomorrow at work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out with Bonneau21's help (thanks!):

I'm connecting to a computer that isn't part of a domain, because of that I need to connect with a local user.

What I did was a slight change to the original script indicating that the user I need to connect with is local:

```
cmdkey /generic:"server ip" /user:"server ip\username" /pass:"password"
```